# Add an access code form to call a unique page based on page without registration

Tags: shortcode, redirect, urls, password

I've seen some similar questions, but they are not totally the same. If I missed in my search, please forgive me. However this what I have so far:

I've created a form that has an input field for the access code and a submit button, as follows:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" name="access">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <input id="access_code" type="Text" name="access_code" value="" />
        <input type="Submit" name="access1" value="Register" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Then on the backend, I started with something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Register'])){
    if(empty($_POST['access_code'])){
        echo "Access Code Must Be Entered";
    }
}

$DisplayForm = True;
if(isset($_POST['Register'])){
    $DisplayForm = False;
    echo $_POST['access_code'];
}

if ($DisplayForm){
    ?>
    <form action="#" method="POST" name="access">
        <input type="Text" name="access_code" value=" " />
        <input type="Submit" name="access1" value="Register" />
    </form>
    <?php
}

echo "<a href="http://www.mysite.com/<?php echo $_POST['access_code'];?>"<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.jpg"></a>"
```

I realize my final echo syntax is broken, but not quite sure how to write out.

All I want to do is have this form redirect a user to a custom page that's based on the access code they have been given and call it with a short code. For example, if the access code is "help", they are sent to a page of http://www.mysite.com/help, or if the password is "contact", they are then sent to a page of http://www.mysite.com/contact.

I initially wanted to base this on the password protection feature in WordPress, where if the page password was also "help" it would just redirect to that URL, but I may be over complicating things.

**So the new code should look like this:**

```
if(isset($_POST['Register'])){
    if(empty($_POST['access_code'])){
        echo "Access Code Must Be Entered";
    }
}

$DisplayForm = True;
if(isset($_POST['Register'])){
    $DisplayForm = False;
    echo $_POST['access_code'];
}

if ($DisplayForm){
    ?>
    <form action="/" method="$_GET" name="access">
        <input type="Text" name="name" value="" />
        <input type="Submit" name="access1" value="Register" />
    </form>
    <?Php
}

wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/'.$_POST['access_code']);
```

I think I understand it all except the execution of the before `get_header()` part. How would I do that?

Comment: This sounds like a great idea for a plugin, and is going to take quite a bit of work if you are new to plugin development. I would suggest reading about how to register shortcode. The rest of the work is going to be cleansing the `$_POST` variable to make sure its valid, and then using `wp_redirect()` to go to the permalink of the page in question. Sounds like a fun project, honestly!

Comment: This question is far too broad for the SE Q & A format. Please show what you have done to research a possible implementation, what code you have attempted, and what issues you have observed with your attempted code.

Comment: I added additional code for what I started with for it on the backend. It would come up easy. I just don't know how to tie it all together and fix my code that actually prints the address.  I wanted to make it a plugin, if someone wants to help, I'm patient. According to my internet search there were quite a few people besides me looking for it. I couldn't find it, so I said let me try building it. This would be my first one.

Comment: I did research how to make into a shortcode by adding it to the functions.php once I have the code. I just need gather the code.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is truly going to be the slug ("secret-page" = example.com/secret-page), you could do something like this...

```
wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/'.$_POST['access_code']);
```

But realize that headers cannot have already been sent, so this needs to happen before `get_header()`. Some more testing would be needed, but that should get you down the right path in principle.

You could also have the form's action be `'/'`, method as `$_GET` and make the `name` of the input be `"name"` (`<input name="name" ...>`).

So if you visit

`example.com/?name=my-secret-page`

you will end up at

`example.com/my-secret-page`

as that is default behavior when using "pretty" permalinks

Comment: I Got the script to Run with a short code under using the plugin **Shortcode Exec PHP**! Even though the script is running perfectly, I still get the  **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mysite.com/html/wp-content/themes/theme/header.php:4) in /mysite.com/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896** Any ideas on how to fix this one?